# Работа с чекбоксом

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте, прошу помочь: суть дела в том, что мне нужно сделать чекбокс который переключается и в нем меняется текст, а так же меняются блоки, которые нужно показать.
Это чекбокс активирован:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А это чекбокс неактивирован.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как сделать так, чтобы менялись блоки типо табов в зависимости от значения чекбокса.

Comment: тут `css` достаточно, но с таким вопросом вам на биржу

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, нормальный вопрос же.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так, ещё только шарик добавить и всё.

```css
#chk {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2em;
  padding: 1px;
  min-width: 10em;
  line-height: 2em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

#chk:checked ~ label {
  background: blue;
}

span {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

span, #chk:checked ~ label .off {
  display: none;
}

.off, #chk:checked ~ label .on {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input id=chk type=checkbox>

<label for=chk>
  <span class="off">Комментарии</span>
  <span class="on">Рецензии</span>
</label>
```